# jQuery tabs to use the live('click') functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Ui Tabs, and I am loading in external content. How do I enable the LIVE() capabilities of the tab?

Like I do with other links etc.

```
$("#button").live('click', function(){});
```

Is this possible with UI Tabs?

I just found this code, but i'm getting really bizarre behavior... seems to be much glitchier.

```
$('#example').tabs({
      load: function(event, ui) {
          $('a', ui.panel).live("click", function() {
              $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
              return false;
          });
      }
   });
```

Comment: @Justin - what bizarre behaviour? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that that is possible. Probably JQueryUI Tabs plugin is overwriting internally click event.

I only can do this: http://jsbin.com/egoca5

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs ul li a').bind('click', function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All visible HTML elements can have a `click` event bound to them using jQuery. Any event you can `bind` to (e.g., `click`) you can also set `live` on, as such, as long as `#button` is a visible HTML element in the page then the `live` method should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think not.
Solution is to perform an action that declare tabs just after loading the external content.